# Is it safe to use the memory address of descoped variables?

Tags: go

Is this code safe? *b* gets descoped when the *if* block ends, but *a* still points to *b*'s memory address. In this simple example it seems to work (it prints the right value), but it is in the language specification that this will always work?

Compiling with -m to check the compiler optimizations, it says that *b* doesn't escape to the heap.

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/ZzYkMg6FqB

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := new(int)
    *a = 10
    if *a > 0 {
        b := 5
        a = &b
    }
    fmt.Println(*a)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly fine.

Scope doesn't matter in Go as much as in C or Rust. Go is a garbage-collected language. As long as the memory can be reached, it won't be freed. In your example, the original value of `a` will be freed during the next GC, as it's not reachable any more.

**Edit:** On stack. In your program, `b` does not escape because it doesn't need to. If you rewrite your program so that `b` will be deleted if allocated on stack (for example, [like this](http://play.golang.org/p/T1Ex7Lfzhi)) you'll see that `b` does escape. Go's escape analysis is clever enough to see such things.

Comment: That applies to the heap, but AFAIK the GC doesn't free anything on the stack. Is it guaranteed that the stack memory that previously used *b* won't be used by any other variable declared in the same function after the *if* ?

Comment: Escaping is from functions (as far as I understand it), not from block scopes.

Comment: Yes, it is for functions and I it works like Ainar-G says: if they escape, they are moved to the heap. But I thought that the stack memory used by variables was "freed" (the stack pointer goes down) for next declarations inside the same function. It seems that it is not the case in Go, and that memory is not made available, so it is use to point to their memory addresses. Am I right?

Comment: Traditionally the stackpointer changes on function invocation and returns.

Answer (score 2):

There are no dangling pointers in Go.

It doesn't matter if `b` is out of scope; `a` now holds that address and would be scanned by the GC.

Comment: However, as far as I know, the GC won't free anything on the stack, because the whole stack is freed when the function ends. So why *b* memory is not used if I declare more variables after the if? isn't the stack used by variables declared inside the *if* made available again? I thought that what's is the stack about.

Comment: Yes, but only if the do not escape. There is no need to think about such stuff until you want to improve the compiler or are under heavy GC pressure and want to create a minimum of garbage. And b's memory is not used by other stuff because that would be a compiler bug.

Answer (score 2):

Code is safe. Any assignment in Go has copy semantic, so

```
a = &b
```

is equivalent to

```
c = &b
a = c
```

assigning to reference you effectively take a copy of this reference

so this sure will also work

```
b := 5
c := &b
a = c
c = nil

fmt.Println(*a)
```

http://play.golang.org/p/fGTYhEXl1S